# Radcombobox hide and display using javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net, radcombobox

I have a div2 which I will show only when RadioButtonList1 value is "Yes" in div1 through javascript function `getvalue().Initially` I am not showing div2 using c# code.

```
<fieldset id="disc" class="nt_generic">
    <div runat="server" id="div1">
        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="RadioButtonList1" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
            OnClick="getvalue()">
            <asp:ListItem Value="Yes" Text="Yes" />
            <asp:ListItem Value="No" Text="No" Selected="True" />
        </asp:RadioButtonList> 
    </div>

    <div id="div2" runat="server">
        <radC:RadComboBox ID="rcb1" EnableLoadOnDemand="true" runat="server" Skin="WebBlue">
        <Items>
            <radC:RadComboBoxItem ID="CondoComboBoxItem" runat="server" Text="A Ground" Value="B" Selected="true" />
            <radC:RadComboBoxItem ID="HomeComboBoxItem" runat="server" Text="B Ground" Value="A" />                            
        </Items>
        </radC:RadComboBox> 
    </div>
</fieldset>

function getvalue()
{
    var value = $('#<%=RadioButtonList1.ClientID %> input[type=radio]:checked').val(); 
    if(value == "Yes")
    {
        if (document.getElementById("<% = div2.ClientID %>") != null)
            document.getElementById("<%= div2.ClientID %>").style.display = "inline-block";
    }
    else
        if (document.getElementById("<% = div2.ClientID %>") != null)
           document.getElementById("<%= div2.ClientID %>").style.display = "none";
}
```

when I am using the  above code as explained the div2 is displaying first and hiding afterwords which i don't want that.

If i add `visible=false` to div2 like below

```
<div id="divTankLocated" runat="server" visible="false">
```

There is no hide and display of div2, but javascript function `getvalue()` is not working, and can't display div2 on change of RadioButtonList1 value.

can some body help me in coming across the above 2 points?

Answer (score 0):

At least part of your problem is due to javascript's automatic semicolon insertion.

ex this:

```
if(value == "Yes")
{
}
```

is turned into:

ex this:

```
if(value == "Yes");
{
}
```

which means that the then section of your if statement is executed every time.  In order to prevent it, you **have** to put your opening `{`'s on the previous line.  Doing that and adding `{ }` pairs to all of your other if statements turns your javascript into this:

```
function getvalue() {
    var value = $('#<%=RadioButtonList1.ClientID %> input[type=radio]:checked').val(); 
    if(value == "Yes") {
        if (document.getElementById("<% = div2.ClientID %>") != null) {
            document.getElementById("<%= div2.ClientID %>").style.display = "inline-block";
        }
    } else if (document.getElementById("<% = div2.ClientID %>") != null) {
           document.getElementById("<%= div2.ClientID %>").style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: after adding semicolon like this if(value == "Yes"); getting JavaScript error msg as value is undefined and adding {} is also is not working for me.

Comment: I am calling getvalue() function in the body_onload() function,  and it started working for me as expected. thxs for all.

Comment: I'm not getting the behavior you describe at the beginning of your answer. I made a fiddle to test it (https://jsfiddle.net/f3kpfmer/1/). Is there a specific version of JavaScript that exhibits this behavior, or am I missing something?